# How to create a correct pivot table with this SQL query in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've this hard SQL pivot table I'm trying to solve. I can't find the solution for it.

```
with cte as (
  select nationality, class as n
  from Fifaklasse
  group by nationality
)
select nationality,
  coalesce(sum(case when n = 'Wereldklasse' then n end), 0) as 'Wereldklasse',
  coalesce(sum(case when n = 'Topklasse'  then n end), 0) as 'Topklasse',
  coalesce(sum(case when n = 'Subtop'  then n end), 0) as 'Subtop'
from cte
group by nationality
```

| player | nationality | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Messi | n1 | World_class |
| Aguero | n1 | World_class |
| Vidal | n2 | Top_class |
| Pinto | n3 | Subtop_class |
| Ronaldo | n3 | World_class |
| Suarez | n4 | World_class |
| Falcao | n4 | Top_class |

RESULT

| Nationality | World_class | Top_class | Subtop_class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| n2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| n3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| n4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You should be summing the value 1 to obtain the counts.  That aside, I would use this version with boolean expressions:

```sql
SELECT nationality,
       SUM(class = 'Wereldklasse') AS Wereldklasse,
       SUM(class = 'Topklasse') AS Topklasse,
       SUM(class = 'Subtop') AS Subtop
FROM Fifaklasse
GROUP BY nationality;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct. But to make it more understandable and work for most other database engines, this should be rewritten as

```
SELECT nationality,
   SUM(iif(klass = 'World', 1, 0)) AS Wereldklasse,
   SUM(iif (klass = 'Top', 1, 0)) AS Topklasse,
   SUM(iif (klass = 'Subtop', 1, 0)) AS Subtop
FROM Fifaklass
GROUP BY nationality
```